# strtok(), file read to char * array

Tags: c, arrays, strtok

I've got a file like this

old  "\t" new1 "\t" new2

ihlçrfhf "\t" oijojio"\t" bkjbiuh

ihlçkstge "\t" ffsdf "\t" dsfsdafd

ih22kshf "\t" oijoij"\t" dsfsdafd

I'm putting all the words respetively on a array of structs,
I'm having a problem with this, all the array slots are getting the same values.

```
typedef struct {
    char * old;
    char * new1; // + frequente
    char * new2; // - frequente
    int n;       // número de repetições
}Data;

int i;
Data data [3500];

char str [200];

i = 0;
while(fgets(str,200,fconv) ){

    data[i].old = strtok_r(str,"\t",&data[i].new2);
    data[i].new1 = strtok_r(NULL,"\t",&data[i].new2);

    i++;

}

while(i--)
    printf("%s\n",data[i].old);
```

I would appreciate an enlightenment
Thank you

Comment: `strdup()` is your friend.  You're storing pointers into the the `str` buffer, which gets overwritten each time you do an `fgets()` call.

Comment: Thank you, I thought that my data[i] pointers would point to different memorys every call.